# How to Display value dynamically in a div tag using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I doing a little project which shows the internet speed by pinging the website and shows the network speed. but the problem is I have to reload every time to get the speed. How to make the div tag which contains the value of the speed to change dynamically.

I tried to load the value of the tag to itself but it doesn't work for me.

The HTML:

```
<h2> <span id="speed"></span> kbps</h2>
```

The JS:

kbitsPerSecond has the value of the speed.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#speed').load('kbitsPerSecond');
refresh();
});

function refresh() {
  setTimeout ( function() {
    $('#speed').fadeOut('slow').load('kbitsPerSecond').fadeIn('slow);
    refresh();
  },200);
  }
```

The tag has to be reloaded dynamically

Comment: Other than the missing quote after the `fadeIn('slow)` part, what you have looks okay. What's it doing when you fix that quote? (setInterval is probably better than setTimeout here, but since you're calling `refresh()` again in the timeout callback, it should still work.)

Comment: Take the refresh() out of the setTimeout function but keep it in the refresh function. you need to fix the typo for slow also its 'slow' not 'slow

Comment: @EvikGhazarian If `refresh()` comes out of the `setTimeout()` function and goes in the main body of `refresh()`, the you will likely cause a `call stack exceeded` error. The `refresh()` call should be in the timer function so it runs at regular intervals.

Comment: yes interval solution is better solution than my recursive with counter solution. I was thinking do the recursion but with counter.

Comment: @EvikGhazarian It's more than just about recursiveness. See my comment below your answer. Your code will not work the way you think it will.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes I deleted it already after thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have two syntax problems.

The JQuery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method takes a URL as the first argument, **you are passing the string 'kbitsPerSecond', which is not a URL**:

```
$('#speed').load('kbitsPerSecond');
```

Your call to `.fadeIn()` is missing a closing quote and, if you want the fade in to happen after the `.load` has completed, you should not chain it after `.load`, but instead include it in the `.load()` callback:

```
$('#speed').fadeOut('slow').load('https://example.com').fadeIn('slow);
```

Now, `setTimeout()` is a one-time timer. Instead of making `refresh()` recursive, use `setInterval()` which is a continuous timer -- it counts to its supplied interval and then fires its callback function, then it counts again and fires again and so on.  However, this will continue even after the page has finished loading, so you'll probably want to cancel the timer at some point.

Also, you don't need two separate `.load()` calls and a separate function as shown below:

```js
let timer = null; // Will hold a reference to the timer
$(function () {
  timer = setInterval (function() {
    $('#speed').fadeOut('slow').load('https://example.com', function(){
      $('#speed').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  },200);  
});

// Uncomment and add the following to some callback that fires when you no longer want the timer to run
//clearInterval(timer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> <span id="speed">TEST</span> kbps</h2>
```

Comment: I tried to do by copying your code but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: @GokulaKrishnan Please elaborate. What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you have any errors showing in the Console? What about the Network tab?

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: https://codepen.io/imgkl/pen/xNEvaE?editors=0110

This is my codepen. I want the network speed to be dynamically updated instead of mannually

Comment: @GokulaKrishnan `kbitsPerSecond` is a variable, not a string, so it shouldn't be in quotes when you reference it as I mention in my answer. Also, it's not a URL, so you shouldn't be using `.load()` in the first place because you aren't actually doing an AJAX request to a separate network location. You are just needing to run a function every so often.

Comment: So instead of using .load() function, what should I use?

Comment: Just use the `.html()` method instead and pass in your variable which holds the result.

Comment: I changed the load function into html but still, the problem persists. Also, I've updated the codepen with your changes, still no luck.

Comment: @GokulaKrishnan I've Forked your CodePen and simplified it a bit [here](https://codepen.io/smar1216/pen/rgWByj?editors=1010). If you open your Console, you'll see that it does run at the specified interval. I just think you haven't created entries to work with, so you don't see updated results.